# Magit commit gives "transient-setup: Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, nil" message

Tags: magit

I apologize if this is a noob-question, I have little experience with Git. I wanted to set up Magit for my projects, and I followed the "Getting Started" section of the Magit manual by creating a new file in a git repository folder for a project that I had already synched using the GitHub GUI and following the instructions. However, after I try to commit in the Magit-buffer, I get the error:

```
transient-setup: Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, nil
```

I saw that the Magit FAQ has a section on problems with committing https://magit.vc/manual/magit/I-am-having-problems-committing.html, but I'm not sure this applies to me. I've configured git in the terminal to use Emacs as an editor, I enabled the emacs systemd-unit, set user variables `VISUAL=emacsclient` and `EDITOR=emacsclient` and if I run:

```
emacsclient -c
```

in the terminal, it opens a buffer. I installed Magit through Melpa and `M-x magit-version` prints:

```
Magit 20230217.2343 [>= 3.3.0.50-git], Git 2.39.2, Emacs 28.2, gnu/linux
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug that has been corrected over night.